# What are the best actions I can take to learn from my errors on meta's usage?

Tags: discussion

Assuming that Meta was for discussing/help to improve the site's performance and the best practices to follow for this purpose, I started making some questions in it. Due to downvotes, it seems I'm not making a good use of Meta.

So I was searching for a [chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/) in meta to start analyzing, one by one, everyone of my most frequent practices to determine if they are productive or not. It seems I am not allowed to use it though. And stackoverflow [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com) doesn't seem to be the proper tool to start a room about this theme.

So, what I want to ask, is:

- Would it be appropiate to start a question for every specific analysis, or it would be too noisy?
- Am I right assuming that I do not have access to any chat created for this purpose yet? Or didn't I research well enough?

I have learnt lots of things thanks to [this awesome website](http://stackoverflow.com), so I will to help as much as I can with the overwhelming amount of activity that Stack Overflow site has to handle, at least, learning about my mistakes. After all, we self-taught (and I use "self-taught" as a way to determine that I didn't learn coding on any college neither anything similar, just researching on my own, **lots of trial-and-error** and, in some cases, asking online) programmers have been a heckofaloadofwork sometimes. And, in order to achieve that, I think a chat would be probably the best option. Or maybe not, who knows?

Comment: If you didn't already know downvotes on meta are different; they reflect a agree/disagree stance and don't affect reputation.

Comment: Thanks. I already know that it doesn't affect reputation. That's not the point I wanted to make. I just want to do things right, and avoid doing them the wrong way.

Comment: You should be able to [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com)...

Comment: By "this site", do you mean Meta or the main site?

Comment: Already looked that one before, but it discouraged me to see that the themes must be the same than Stack Overflow, so I thought it would be inappropiate to open a room there for this. When saying "this awesome website" I meant Stack Overflow. ServerFault is also great. Are you meaning it would be the right way to go?

Comment: On the title, I meant Meta site.

Comment: @SebasSBM: "doesn't affect reputation" isn't the important part of jpw's comment, it's "downvotes on meta are different; they reflect a agree/disagree stance". If you're getting downvotes, that doesn't (necessarily) mean you're not using Meta right, it just (maybe) means people are disagreeing with your suggestions or analyses. They may still think they're interesting and worth having here. Or they may not. But just taking the downvotes to mean "I'm doing something wrong" means you haven't got the point yet.

Comment: This: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44188/how-do-i-participate-in-meta-and-not-die-trying

Comment: Best advice to anyone struggling with Meta, or the main site, is to read more and write less.

Comment: Also this: http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If you don't find your question here on the child meta there's a good chance it was asked before the split search http://meta.stackexchange.com/ as well

Comment: @apaul34208 I discovered chat.meta.stackexchange before asking. I tried to point it in the question. Sorry for the misunderstanding. In any case, I'm glad you participated. I'll make sure to gather all the documentation you have offered in this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are over 9.3 million questions on Stack Overflow.

Let me rephrase that.  There are over 9.3 million examples of how to use Stack Overflow as an asker.  Perhaps more importantly, next to every question, is a score indicating how well received the question was.  Also, some of these questions will be marked as closed.

And how about one more rephrasing. There are over 9.3 million reasons why the question you're *about* to ask doesn't even *need* to be asked at all.  Your specific question might not have been asked exactly, but perhaps if you [break your problem down a bit more](http://importblogkit.com/2015/05/how-do-you-eat-an-elephant/), its individual parts have already been solved on Stack Overflow.

How should you use this site?  First and foremost, primarily, as a repository of already-asked-questions-and-answers.  Most likely, the solution to your problem already exists.  And spending time searching for your solution in previously asked questions will actually tend to yield better results faster.

We can apply all this same reasoning to the meta as well.  The meta has far fewer examples (just over 12 thousand), but it's scope is also significantly smaller.

Also, plenty of questions can be answered simply by [taking a tour](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tour), [visiting the help center](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help), and [reading this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta).

Once you've visited those three pages, if anything is unclear, search through the existing questions on the site to see if any of these clarify your question.  If you're still left unsure, now you're ready to ask a question, but when you do, be certain that your question shows your research effort.  When appropriate, link to documentation from the help center, and never hesitate to include links of past questions relevant to your question.

Comment: I think he's asking how to use Meta, not how to use SO.

Comment: @abarnert Answer now covers both.  Question is a little unclear, so I just addressed both.

Comment: @nhgrif Good approach. That's how I used them for months (or even years, I can't really tell), until the day I didn't find the answer I was looking for, day that I created my account. Duplicates are sometimes hard to find. And, actually, when I post I tend to post more answers than questions.

Comment: @abarnert thanks for clarification. I tend sometimes to have difficults to make my point.

Comment: @SebasSBM: I think dups tend to be easier to find on Meta than on SO. Partly because they're less likely to involve searching for symbols, or trying to figure out the terminology for something you don't know, but also because it's so much smaller and more focused, and there aren't millions of bad questions swamping the good ones… Then again, I've only got something like 6 questions on SO and 1 on MSO or MSE, so maybe I'm just lucky at searching. :)

Comment: @nhgrif This leads me to another interesting question: what are the most rapid ways to find duplicates? Maybe using SQL queries over post's tables combined with regexps? (retoric questions). I'll research it someday... it's 03:15 at this side of the planet... I should sleep some. Thanks for your time guys, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Well, sometimes duplicates are hard to find.  I'm not sure I've mastered it.  Mostly the best way to find duplicates is to read dozens of questions a day for a few months in a specific tag, and you'll suddenly start realizing that everyone using [tag:parse.com] is an idiot asking the same question over and over... but if the duplicate is non-obvious, it can be worth posting the question and letting it be closed as a duplicate.  A duplicate serves as a sign post pointing to the actual answer but with different keywords and terms.

Comment: Duplicates with a significantly different set of keywords and search terms are actually *good* to have.

Comment: Before I sleep, I'd like to say that I don't see StackOverflow just as a place to gather information anymore; also as a good training ground to keep improving myself as the professional programmer I've become.

Comment: @SebasSBM: That's a good attitude. And SO is also a way to gather information indirectly—looking up things you otherwise wouldn't have in order to answer someone else's question, or occasionally even writing the "obviously right" answer only for someone to demonstrate that in this case the "obvious" is wrong.